# AWS ELB redirect behind SSH tunnel doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-elb, portforwarding

We have an HTTP server listening on port X, and an AWS Classic HTTP Load Balancer, listening on the same port X and forwarding to the host port X.

The ELB is not routable to the internet, so to connect to it, we create an SSH tunnel from a local port Y to the ELB port X over a bastion host.

Simple HTTP requests work ok, however when the service return an HTTP redirect response (303), the ELB translates it to port Y.

So it looks like:
http://localhost:Y --> (303 redirected) http://localhost:X/login

When skipping the ELB and tunnelling directly to the service host, redirects work fine.

Any way to configure the ELB to translate the redirections to the originating port, as specified in the HTTP Host header?

Comment: ELBs don't rewrite redirects. Connecting directly to the web server using something like `curl -v http://localhost:X -H 'Host:localhost:Y'` should prove that the server is actually issuing this redirect when the conditions are truly identical. It might be better if you put the real port numbers in the question since the specific numbers could actually prove relevant.

Comment: Indeed the server is issuing the redirect, but when connecting to it directly over a port forwarding, it issues the correct one. I suspect that the ELB modifies the `Host` header - is that so @Michael-sqlbot ?

Comment: Another option is that the service is creating the redirects based on the `X-Forwarded-` headers which are added by the ELB.. is there a way to disable them?

Comment: No, the ELB does  not modify the `Host` header, either, but the point of the suggested `curl` test is to cause the server to emit the same incorrect redirect without the ELB in the loop, which I am confident will happem with the headers set as the browser sets them.  The `X-Forwarded-*` headers represent correct, standard behavior, and can't be disabled in HTTP mode.

Comment: Ran `tcpdump` on the service host and got the following host header: `host: localhost:X`. Since the browser is unaware of port X, it means that something along the way changes the `Host` header, and it probably IS the load balancer after all. @Michael-sqlbot any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide the real numbers of X and Y so I can try to replicate this behavior with an SSH tunnel and Classic ELB.  I need the exact values you're using, and please confirm that it's HTTP and not HTTPS.